# Discrete Structure: $\{x:2x\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have this one multiple choice question but my answer seems wrong (both "The set of even numbers starting from 1" and "The set of even integers"). Am I misunderstanding it?

As $x$ is a natural number it can only be something from $\{1,2,3...\}$, right?

[image]

Comment: It would best to type any relevant info into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the numbers $x$ for which $2x \in \mathbb{N}$.

So if $2x = n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $x = n/2$, i.e., $x$ is half of a natural number.

The natural numbers are: $1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots$

Dividing by two yields: $0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, \ldots$

So **none** of the displayed answers is correct; the third choice is close, but it is missing $0.5$.

Comment: Taking $x$ from where? $x$ may be allowed to be a rational number, or not

Comment: @I.Padilla The specification is that doubling any such $x$ results in a natural number; so, I am asserting that $x$ is of the form $n/2$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 0):

Read aloud $\{x~:~2x\in\Bbb N\}$ is the set of all values of $x$ (*from the universal set in question*) such that $2x$ is a natural number.

Depending on whether you include zero in $\Bbb N$ and depending on what you consider your universal set to be, the set itself will look differently.

Many people, myself included, prefer to consider $0$ a natural number though there are still several people who follow the other convention where $0$ is not a natural number.

As for the universal set, it is most common to take $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ as the universal set if not otherwise mentioned and no other context is available.

With these two assumptions we would have:

$$\{x\color{grey}{\in \Bbb R}~:~2x\in\Bbb N\} = \{0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,\dots\}$$

Taking $\Bbb N$ instead to not include $0$ this would be $\{0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,\dots\}$

With instead the assumption that the universal set is $\Bbb N$ and zero is included in the set of natural numbers, this would instead be

$$\{x\color{grey}{\in\Bbb N}~:~2x\in\Bbb N\} = \{0,1,2,3,\dots\}=\Bbb N$$

With the assumption that the universal set is $\Bbb N$ and zero is not included we would again have $=\{1,2,3,\dots\}=\Bbb N$

None of these four answers are included as an option...